# Where can I put a JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a homework assignment that requires me to make an Array. My code works, but I'm not sure if it's considered as using an Array. If anyone could clarify this for me and tell me what code I can replace with an Array, I would be very appreciative!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Chapter 09 Arrays</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Student Scores</h1>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr style="background-color:grey">
                    <td width='25%' align='center'><b>First Name</B></td>
                    <td width='25%' align='center'><b>Last Name</b></td>
                    <td width='25%' align='center'><b>Score<b></td>
                    <td width='25%' align='center'>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id='first_name'></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id='last_name'></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="score" id='score' style='text-align:right'></td>
                    <td width='25%' align='center'>
                        <input type="button" value="Add Student Score" onClick='javascript:addScore();'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <h2>Student Scores</h2>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" readonly name='results' id='results'>
        </textarea>
        <br />
        Average Score: <input type="text" name="avg" id='avg' disabled="disabled"><br>
        <br />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        <input type="button" value="Sort By Last Name" onClick='javascript:sortScore();'>
        <input type="button" value="Clear Scores" onClick='javascript:clearScores();'>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var firstName = [];
        var lastName = [];
        var score = [];
        var aDisplay = [];

        function resetField() {
        }

        function clearScores() {
            firstName = [];
            lastName = [];
            score = [];
            aDisplay = [];
            document.getElementById('avg').value='';
            document.getElementById('results').value='';
            resetEntry();
        }

        function resetEntry() {
            document.getElementById('first_name').value='';
            document.getElementById('last_name').value='';
            document.getElementById('score').value='';
        }

        function addScore() {
            var tempFirstName = getFieldValue('first_name');
            var tempLastName = getFieldValue('last_name');
            var tempScore = getFieldValue('score');

            if (tempFirstName == '') {
                alert('Specify a value for first name');
                document.getElementById('first_name').focus();
                return;
            }

            if (tempLastName == '') {
                alert('Specify a value for last name');
                document.getElementById('last_name').focus();
                return;
            }

            if (tempScore == '') {
                alert('Specify a value for score');
                document.getElementById('score').focus();
                return;
            }

            temp = "";
            total = 0;
            var tempAvg = 0.0;
            firstName.push(getFieldValue('first_name'))
            lastName.push(getFieldValue('last_name'))
            score.push(getFieldValue('score'))
            aDisplay.push(getFieldValue('last_name') + "," + getFieldValue('first_name') + "," + parseInt(getFieldValue('score')))

            for(i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
                total += parseInt(score[i]);
            }

            tempAvg = (total / score.length);
            tempAvg = tempAvg.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById('avg').value = tempAvg;
            listScores();
            resetEntry();
        }

        function sortScore() {
            aDisplay.sort();
            listScores();
        }

        function listScores() {
            temp = "";
            document.getElementById('results').value = '';
            for(i = 0; i < aDisplay.length; i++) {
                temp += aDisplay[i] + "\n";
            }
            document.getElementById('results').value = temp;
        }
        function getFieldValue(p) {
            var v = "";
            if (document.getElementById(p) != null && document.getElementById(p).value > "") {
                v = document.getElementById(p).value;
            }
            return v;
        }
        clearScores();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *What* should be considered being an array? You use several of them, yes.

Comment: looks fine, btw there is a codereview site on stackexchange now (may still be in beta)

Comment: Careful with variable `i`, it's not been defined with `var` so it's leaking to the global scope, although all your code seems to be in the global scope, not a good idea...

Comment: Could you please format your code so that it is readable? That makes it easier for us to help you. Thank you! Also, what do you refer to by **it** in: *"My code works but I'm not sure if its considered an Array"* ? The code itself is not an array of course. The clearer you describe your problem, the more helpful answers you will get. What is your actual question? I don't understand what problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I'll try to help you:

1. General term http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array#In_computer_science
2. If you learn about arrays in context of JavaScript programming language, then (as most of the time) you better read about it on Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Since it's your homework, try to understand what the term is and what it means in the context of your assignment.

Comment: Ah thank you! That was helpful! So i guess the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

All of these are very clearly you using arrays, and properly.

```
var firstName = [];
var lastName = [];
var score = [];
var aDisplay = [];
.......
firstName.push(getFieldValue('first_name')) 
lastName.push(getFieldValue('last_name')) 
score.push(getFieldValue('score')) 
aDisplay.push(getFieldValue('last_name') + "," + getFieldValue('first_name') + "," + parseInt(getFieldValue('score')))
.......
for(i=0;i<score.length;i++){
total += parseInt(score[i]);
}
```